# what should I do when user upgrade subscribe in apple app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now when user upgrade the auto renew subscribe product in apple app purchase, the apple server will send a  `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` message to my develop server. Now I am received the message successfully. But I did not know what should I do to handle the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` message properly. I read the doc and search from internet and tell me the apple will take effect the new upgraded subscribtion the next period. what should I do when received the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` message?

I have think one way that save the new upgraded subscribe record and mark the new subscribed record not valid until recieved switch message from apple server. should I do it like this?

now I am get the subscribe product by using product id and expire date, I must add another field to mark the new upgraded product not valid. I just want to know how to handle the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` message the best way. The same as downgrade auto renew product, any suggestion is appriciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is only telling you that the `product_id` will change.

As you said, in case of an up-grade/cross-grade, it will change right away. In case of a down-grade it will change at the next `expires_date`.

To know if you should change the current product associated to your user, look into the last element of the `latest_receipt_info` (ordered by `web_order_line_item_id`) and check the `product_id`. If its value match the upgraded product, you should change, otherwise no.

If it didn't change, you'll get the new product:

- in case of an up-grade/cross-grade: an `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL` S2S will succeed to the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` (and you'll have to check the `latest_receipt_info.product_id` property, as described before)
- in case of down-grade: since the `expires_date` will be past, you'll need to check with the [/verifyReceipt API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt) if the subscription has been renewed. By looking to the `product_id` property, you'll detect the down-grade.

Comment: should I store the purchased auto renew  product id into user table? @romainsalles

Comment: You can store it if you want to know that your user will downgrade at the next renewal date (with this information, you'll be able to activate marketing actions to keep him on its current subscription). Same thing with the `auto_renew_status` property, if you want to take marketing actions to avoid that a user definitely unsubscribe from your app. These 2 things are not mandatory, but always better if you have time for marketing :)